# How to create DataTable using jQuery in UI of MVC4?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to create `DataTable` using jQuery same as like which is mentioned in the below image:

[image]

I am very week in **jQuery**. So please don't ask what you tried question to me. I don't know how to create the `Datatable` in my View same as like this Format.

Please any one help me "How to create a `DataTable` in the above mentioned Format with `Label` and `TextBoxes`?

Comment: use this...https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: it provides with examples and easy to use

Comment: Yes I saw that page Pranav .                                                 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div Id= "myTable">
Name: <input type="text"><br>
Email: <input type="text"><br>
</div>

</body>
</html>  I tried same as like this this is correct Format

Comment: i don't see a table here. You mean table with this fields?

Comment: Yes Teo I want to create a Datatable  with Labels and Texboxes .

Comment: @snehaPriya can you please elaborate what you want to do with this? means you want to enter data or only showing data...if showing data only then is it editable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy. you have to add jQuery dataTables plugin in your page

```
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

and then create normal `table` with `tr` `td` `th` and use below code to convert it into datable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourTableId').DataTable();
});
```

you can find more detail line css theme and other options in [this link](https://www.datatables.net/)

Comment: yes that  only I did Totalo Doto Neto  See my command of Pranav

Comment: did you add dataTables scripts after your jQuery and JQueryUI script or before it?

Comment: I add J-query in the Head Section and I called the HTML Element  in between the jquery                                                                                                   $(document).ready(function)(){
  $('#mytable').DataTable();
}